# NPM installation of plugin gives GYP errors

Tags: node.js, cordova, gyp

I'm trying to install a Share-Button plugin for my mobile app but when I type "npm i --save-dev share-button" I get a long list of GYP error codes. I am only a student and pretty new to programming so I apologize if the answer to my problem is seemingly simple. I tried updating Nodejs, GYP and NPM but so far no luck. These are the errors I'm getting:

C:\Users\Marketing1-Plugged\Documents\App\Soundboard>npm install share-button

> gyp ERR! build error
>
> gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit
>   (C:\Users\Marketing1-Plugged\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
>
> gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10586
>
> gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"
>   "C:\Users\Marketing1-Plugged\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   "rebuild"
>
> gyp ERR! cwd
>   C:\Users\Marketing1-Plugged\node_modules\pioneer\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
>
> gyp ERR! node -v v5.7.1
>
> gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.0
>
> gyp ERR! not ok
>
> npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.1.0 utf-8-validate@1.1.0 install:
>   `node-gyp rebuild`
>
> npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.1.0 Exit status 1
>
> C:\Users\Marketing1-Plugged
>   +-- phonegap@6.0.1
>   +-- share-button@1.0.3 | `-- pioneer@0.11.7 |`-- cucumber@0.3.3  (git+https://github.com/joshtombs/cucumber-js.git#78f79263e5855dd189e4bbe792cc6a34d7efcd19)
>   `-- slideout@0.1.12
>
> > npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> >     'C:\Users\Marketing1-Plugged\package.json' npm WARN Marketing1-Plugged
> >     No description npm WARN Marketing1-Plugged No repository field. npm
> >     WARN Marketing1-Plugged No README data npm WARN Marketing1-Plugged No
> >     license field.

Answer (score 0):

Can you place the package.json file in the specified path

and also try upgrade your version of npm

> npm install npm -g --ca=null

Comment: I tried installing it again but now I get a different error  npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Marketing1-Plugged\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i" "--save-dev" "share-button"
npm ERR! node v5.7.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.0
npm ERR! code ENOSELF

npm ERR! Refusing to install share-button as a dependency of itself
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>